# how does it works "$_ & 1" in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am perl beginner, I am reading upon `grep` function to filter a list. I came across the following program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize an array
my @array = qw(3 4 5 6 7 8 9);

# first syntax form:
my @subArray = grep { $_ & 1 } @array;
```

the statement `my @subArray = grep { $_ & 1 } @array;` returns odd-numbers in  `@array`. I didn't understand how the expression(`$_ & 1`) works. I searched in Google but did not found any useful links.

- Is that any kind of special operator ?
- Are there any other variants of that **EXPR** ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: FYI: this is a very neat hack **that should never be used in production code** unless the operation of finding only odd elements is benchmarked to be a performance bottleneck in a more-readable implementation.

Comment: @DVK Hm, As for my interest: does this tip used? `$_||=$val`

Comment: @loldop - `||=` operator is perfectly proper idiomatic Perl, not a hack. However, using `$_` as opposed to using a self-documentedly-named-variavle is very frequently a sign of poorly written code unless used in a very short `map`/`grep` block.

Comment: @VARamesh, I think, you could use this expression: `($_%2)` elements, that have rest 1 in ring modulo 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$_` is the variable holding the currently tested value, `&` is the binary AND operator, and `1` is just the number one. This expression combines all the bits of both `$_` and `1` with each other by logical AND. So it returns 1 if the value is odd and 0 if the value is even.

As an example, lets assume $_ is 123 then it's binary representation would be `1111011`. The decimal number 1 would be `00000001`, so combining all bits by AND you get

```
123 = 1111011
  1 = 0000001
      - AND -
      0000001 = 1
```

Another example `200 & 100`

```
200 = 11001000
100 = 01100100
      - AND --
      01000000 = 64
```

Comment: In the second example(`200 & 100`), does the answer is `64` or my way of conversion is wrong ?

Comment: You are right, that has to be 64 of course. The 128 was an error on my part.

Answer (score 4):

As many have pointed out, `&` is the bitwise-and operator. This means that the two numbers that are compared are turned into bits and compared:

For example, `3 & 1` returns `1`, which evaluates to true inside the grep:

```
Num | Bits
----+-----
  3 | 1 1
& 1 | 0 1
----+-----
  1 | 0 1   <- result of 'and'ing each bit column
```

Similarly, `4 & 1` returns `0`, which is false:

```
Num | Bits
----+-------
  4 | 1 0 0
& 1 | 0 0 1
----+-------
  0 | 0 0 0  <- all zeros because no column contains 1 & 1
```

---

That said, An alternative way to filter odd numbers is to `mod` the number with 2:

```
my @odd = grep { $_ % 2 } 1 .. 7;    # 1, 3, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep{ $_ & 1}
```

Will go over every element of your array and do a bit-wise match with 1
This means that grep will match any element that has a 1 as last (lsb) bit.
Since only odd numbers have a 1 as lsb this will only return odd numbers

```
&  is the bitwise AND
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_` is the current expression. In this case each array element.

`&` is the binary AND operator.

So, in short, the `grep` will match any array element that is an odd number.

The use of `$_` with `grep` is documented in the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).
The meaning of `&` is also in the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And).

Answer (score 0):

`$_` is a variable set by the grep function. Most of the perl functions manipulate $_ if not specified otherwise. `Grep` calls the defined anonymous sub  (which is `{ $_ & 1 }`) for each elements of @array and makes a bitwise `&`. If the result is a true value, then it is added to the resulting array.